# SQL Server - group and number matching contiguous values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a list of stock transactions and I am using Over(Partition By) to calculate the running totals (positions) by security.  Over time a holding in a particular security can be long, short or flat.  I am trying to find an efficient way to extract only the transactions relating to the current position for each security.

I have created a simplified [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8fb7bb/5) to show what I have so far.  The cte query generates the running total for each security (code_id) and identifies when the holdings are long (L), short (s) or flat (f).  What I need is to group and number matching contiguous values of L, S or F for each code_id.

What I have so far is this:

```
; WITH RunningTotals as
(
SELECT 
    *,
    RunningTotal = sum(qty) OVER (Partition By code_id Order By id) 
FROM
    TradeData
), LongShortFlat as
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        LSF = CASE 
                WHEN RunningTotal > 0 THEN 'L'
                WHEN RunningTotal < 0 THEN 'S'
                ELSE 'F'
            END
    FROM
        RunningTotals
)
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    LongShortFlat r
```

I think what I need to do is create a GroupNum column by applying a row_number for each group of L, S and F within each code_id so the results look like this:

```
id code_id     qty  RunningTotal     LSF    GroupNum
  1       1       5             5      L            1
  2       1       2             7      L            1
  3       1       7            14      L            1
  4       1      -3            11      L            1
  5       1      -5             6      L            1
  6       1      -6             0      F            2
  7       1       5             5      L            3
  8       1       5            10      L            3
  9       1      -2             8      L            3
 10       1      -4             4      L            3
 11       2       5             5      L            1
 12       2       3             8      L            1
 13       2      -4             4      L            1
 14       2      -2             2      L            1
 15       2      -2             0      F            2
 16       2       6             6      L            3
 17       2      -5             1      L            3
 18       2      -5            -4      S            4
 19       2       2            -2      S            4
 20       2       4             2      L            5
 21       2      -5            -3      S            6
 22       2      -2            -5      S            6
 23       3       5             5      L            1
 24       3       2             7      L            1
 25       3       1             8      L            1
```

I am struggling to generate the GroupNum column.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please explain the logic for your different groups.  Don't make people who want to help reverse engineer your code.  Your question is also unclear:  do you want the "highest groupNum" or the "last occurrence"?

Comment: Sorry, finding it hard to put into words and I realize now that although I simplified what I am doing I probably didn't simplify enough for this question.  I have change the question a bit but to clarify, all I need is a way to generate the numbers shown in the GroupNum column above.  These are row numbers that group matching contiguous values in the LSF column together.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for making this question a bit more complicated than it needed to be but for the sake of closure I have found a solution using the lag function.

In order to achieve what I wanted I continued my cte above with the following:

```
, a as
(
SELECT 
    *, 
    Lag(LSF, 1, LSF) OVER(Partition By code_id ORDER BY id) AS prev_LSF,
    Lag(code_id, 1, code_id) OVER(Partition By code_id ORDER BY id) AS prev_code
FROM
    LongShortFlat
), b as
(
SELECT
    id, 
    LSF,
    code_id, 
    Sum(CASE 
            WHEN LSF <> prev_LSF AND code_id = prev_code
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END) OVER(Partition By code_id ORDER BY id) AS grp 
FROM
    a
)
select * from b order by id
```

Here is the updated [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8fb7bb/8).

Answer (score 1):

[Revised]

Sorry about that, I read your question too quickly. I came up with a solution using a recursive common table expression (below), then saw that you've worked out a solution using `LAG`. I'll post my revised query anyway, for posterity. Either way, the resulting query is (imho) pretty ugly.

```
;WITH cteBaseAgg
 as (
     --  Build the "sum increases over time" data
     SELECT
        row_number() over (partition by td.code_id order by td.code_id, td.Id)  RecurseKey
       ,td.code_id
       ,td.id
       ,td.qty
       ,sum(tdPrior.qty)  RunningTotal
       ,case
          when sum(tdPrior.qty) > 0 then 'L'
          when sum(tdPrior.qty) < 0 then 'S'
          else 'F'
        end  LSF
      from dbo.TradeData  td
       inner join dbo.TradeData  tdPrior
        on tdPrior.code_id = td.code_id  --  All for this code_id
         and tdPrior.id <= td.Id         --  For this and any prior Ids
      group by
        td.code_id
       ,td.id
       ,td.qty
    )
,cteRecurse
  as (
      --  "Set" the first row for each code_id
      SELECT
        RecurseKey
       ,code_id
       ,id
       ,qty
       ,RunningTotal
       ,LSF
       ,1  GroupNum

       from cteBaseAgg
       where RecurseKey = 1
      --  For each succesive row in each set, check if need to increment GroupNum
      UNION ALL SELECT
        agg.RecurseKey
       ,agg.code_id
       ,agg.id
       ,agg.qty
       ,agg.RunningTotal
       ,agg.LSF
       ,rec.GroupNum + case when rec.LSF = agg.LSF then 0 else 1 end
      from cteBaseAgg  agg
       inner join cteRecurse  rec
        on rec.code_id = agg.code_id
         and agg.RecurseKey - 1 = rec.RecurseKey
     )
--  Show results
SELECT
   id
  ,code_id
  ,qty
  ,RunningTotal
  ,LSF
  ,GroupNum
 from cteRecurse
 order by
   code_id
  ,id
```

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to be regenerating what I already have from my cte query.  I am looking for a way to generate the GroupNum column shown.

Comment: Original answer has been overhauled.

Comment: Thanks Philip.  Your solution is actually a useful complement to mine as yours will work on pre SQL Server prior 2012 versions whereas mine will only work on 2012 and above.  You just need to include the GroupNum field in your output and you're all good.

Comment: One final comment about this, in case anyone wants to use it in pre SQL Server 2012, it only really works for very small datasets.  I increased the test dataset to 25k records and the query is still running 45 mins later.  My solution for 2012 and above took 1.5 seconds!!!!  If you have larger datasets in pre 2012 then a cursor might be a bit quicker.